# Copying Linq query to List

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

```
'Read RESX file and returns a List(Of ResXDataNode)
Dim allNodes = getResourceData()

'Linq Query to extract the nodes
Dim movedNodes = From rowNodes In allNodes _
                 Where rowNodes.Comment = oldRowNumber _
                 Select rowNodes
```

Will this:

```
Dim nodesToMove As List(Of ResXDataNode) = New List(Of ResXDataNode)

For Each movedNode As ResXDataNode In movedNodes
    nodesToMove.Add(movedNode)
Next
```

or

```
Dim nodesToMove As List(Of ResXDataNode) = movedNodes.ToList
```

Provide two separate copies of the node? Or will the List and Linq query still be referencing the same data?

Answer (score 3):

They will still refer to the same objects - that won't create any extra `ResXDataNode` objects.

By the way, calling `movedNodes.ToList()` would be simpler than manually adding each one...

Now it's perfectly possible that each time you iterate over `movedNodes` it *might* create new objects - it really depends on what it's doing, and you haven't shown how it's being created. But copying to the list *doesn't* create new objects.

Comment: I put the rest of the code up. I tried .ToList and it seemed to do what I wanted. Interestingly enough, it works differently than just looping and adding.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: It shouldn't work differently - and it won't create new node objects.

Answer (score 3):

If `ResXDataNode` is a reference type they still will be referencing the same objects, if it is a value type a copy is created and added to the new list.

Edit: [`ResXDataNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxdatanode.aspx)  is a reference type, so the new list will still refer to the same objects.

Comment: You are correct. I guess a .Clone method is not needed. Because of the .ToList.